# Only some apps on my moto g5 have internet access

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, connection-issues, motorola, motorola-moto-g5

I have had a Motorola Moto G5 for around a month now and today, suddenly it seems that apps like Instagram are unable to connect to the internet. 
I have restarted the phone, restarted the modem, reset the internet settings, forgot the wifi network, reconnected but nothing seems to work. When I turn on my 4G everything works fine. When I open chrome, I can access Google. 
My Version of Android is 7.0 and it has the July 2018 Security patch level that was recently installed, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ah Ha! I may know the issue. My ISP, Talk Talk, has randomly enabled Kid Safe and is blocking some websites including the servers of the apps with no internet. When I use a VPN, everything starts working again due to KidSafe being bypassed. After disabling, it all starts working again without the VPN!